# Diode ring mixer (difference between strong and weak LO)

Tags: rf, mixer

I've built a simple diode ring mixer according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=junuEwmQVQ8&t=355s) video. The mixer works, checked it on several frequencies. The application of the mixer is to isolate the IF from a 27 MHz FSK signal.  As my LO I have a 27 MHz colpitts with 120 mVpp, and as RF I connected another 27Mhz colpitts with different capacitor values to produce a small frequency difference (although I suspect the difference would've been there even without extra measures). Here's the output on the scope:

[image]

I have a couple of questions in regards to the setup.

1) The LO voltage is quite low, around 120 mVpp. As far as I understand the mixing still happens even if the voltages are below the diode forward voltage, however would the IF frequency be more pronounced if I increased the LO voltage? In other words, does increasing the LO voltage increase the "quality" of mixing? I tried feeding the signal into a low pass filter however the low frequency signal was almost entirely lost, so I thought maybe increasing the LO voltage would make filtering and demodulation easier.

2) Any environmental change (what items are around the circuit, if I am touching the power cable or not) tends to change the frequency, which is quite problematic if we are talking about FSK demodulation. Is this something to be expected? I don't understand how me touching the power cable should change the oscillation frequency of either LO or the RF I am feeding into the mixer. Can I somehow reduce this effect (besides building proper enclosure)?

Comment: colpitts osc f is affected by load C and stray capacitance from insufficient buffering, so insufficient to drive . LO level must exceed 2 diode drops Vpp in order to invert phase of RF. Then diode current load impedance effects on LO are limited by any series load R, normally low for fast response. Diode choice also affects behaviour.  Another mixer is CMOS XOR gate, which is avail. in cd4046 PLL etc.

Comment: I though about feeding the low freq IF into cd4046 to demodulate the FSK. I didn't think it could operate at 27MHz so never thought about feeding signals directly in. Am I wrong on that?

Comment: pls. learn to search for your answer and not be spoon-fed.  Digikey has hundreds of PLL's and a dozen different varieties of 74xxx Cd4046 was 1st generation , now 74HCxx 74LVxx 74HCxx etc http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lv4046a.pdf

Comment: The video you referenced clearly explains that the mixer gives little output while L.O. swings through its zero crossing. A low-amplitude L.O. swings almost all of its sinewave in this region....only at its very limit of +ve peak and -ve peak might you get mixing action. So as Tony says, you need more L.O. amplitude. You can go overboard: too much L.O. causes excess diode current on peaks, and is wasted, heating diodes.

Comment: The usual distinction is between strong and weak mixers.

Comment: Yeah, I even ordered a couple of CD74HC4046-s, just thought I may be wrong, since you mentioned cd4046. Anyways, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: HC won't cut the mustard but TI do do a 4046 that works well into the 30 MHz region.